# Merge two count datename queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

**Query**

```
SELECT 
       DATENAME(dw, O1.CreationDateTime) AS 'Day of the week', 
       DATENAME(hh, O1.CreationDateTime) AS hour, 
       COUNT(*) AS 'Nr. Orders'
FROM 
       Orders AS O1
WHERE 
       O1.CreationDateTime >= '2015-10-01' 
GROUP BY 
       DATENAME(dw, O1.CreationDateTime), DATENAME(hh, O1.CreationDateTime)
ORDER BY 
       [Day of the week], CAST(DATENAME(hh, O1.CreationDateTime) as int)
```

Gives the total number of orders for each hour of each weekday

**Result**

```
Weekday Hour    Nr.Orders
Friday  0   10
Friday  1   11
Friday  2   2
```

The goal is to get the AVERAGE amount of orders for each hour of the day. However some days have no orders those days should not be counted.
To solve this problem I wrote the select distinct query below.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
       DATENAME(dw,Formatteddate.Date) AS "Day of the week",
       COUNT(*) AS "Weekdays in period"
FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT
       ((CONVERT (date,O2.CreationDateTime,112))) AS Date
FROM Orders AS O2
WHERE 
       O2.CreationDateTime >= '2015-10-01' 
       ) AS Formatteddate
GROUP BY DATENAME(dw,Formatteddate.Dates)
```

It counts for example the number of fridays with orders like shown below.

**Result**

```
Day of the week | Week days in period (with order)
    Friday            32
    Monday            30
    Saturday          21
```

> Basically my questions is how two merge those two query's I used outer
>   apply as a workaround. However it is very slow due to the fact it
>   checks each row. I think I need to use the over clause but I have no
>   idea how with the datename function.

The end result should look like this to make counting the average easy.

```
Weekday Hour    Nr.Orders   Weekdays in period
Friday  0        10            32
Friday  1        11            32
Friday  2        2             32
Friday  3        2             32
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with joining the two queries together on the day?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its totally fine. Cant understand why I overlooked that option. Maybe because I was finding the query a bit large for a simple result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables together on the day of the week:

```
SELECT t1.[Day of the week] AS Weekday,
       t1.hour,
       t1.[Nr. Orders],
       COALESCE(t2.[Weekdays in period], 0)
FROM
(
    SELECT DATENAME(dw, O1.CreationDateTime) AS 'Day of the week', 
           DATENAME(hh, O1.CreationDateTime) AS hour, 
           COUNT(*) AS 'Nr. Orders'
    FROM Orders AS O1
    WHERE O1.CreationDateTime >= '2015-10-01' 
    GROUP BY DATENAME(dw, O1.CreationDateTime),
             DATENAME(hh, O1.CreationDateTime)
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DATENAME(dw,Formatteddate.Date) AS "Day of the week",
           COUNT(*) AS "Weekdays in period"
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT (date,O2.CreationDateTime, 112) AS Date
        FROM Orders AS O2
        WHERE O2.CreationDateTime >= '2015-10-01' 
    ) AS Formatteddate
    GROUP BY DATENAME(dw,Formatteddate.Dates)
) t2
    ON t1.[Day of the week] = t2.[Day of the week]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining on the day:

```
WITH DayO AS (
SELECT 
       DATENAME(dw,Formatteddate.Date) AS DayOfWeek,
       COUNT(*) AS PeriodDays
FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT
       ((CONVERT (date,O2.CreationDateTime,112))) AS Date
FROM Orders AS O2
WHERE 
       O2.CreationDateTime >= '2015-10-01' 
       ) AS Formatteddate
GROUP BY DATENAME(dw,Formatteddate.Dates) 
)

, HourO AS (
SELECT 
       DATENAME(dw, O1.CreationDateTime) AS DayOfWeek, 
       DATENAME(hh, O1.CreationDateTime) AS OrdHour, 
       COUNT(*) AS NumOrd
FROM 
       Orders AS O1
WHERE 
       O1.CreationDateTime >= '2015-10-01' 
GROUP BY 
       DATENAME(dw, O1.CreationDateTime), DATENAME(hh, O1.CreationDateTime)
ORDER BY 
       [DayOfWeek], CAST(DATENAME(hh, O1.CreationDateTime) as int)
)

SELECT ho.DayOfWeek as Weekday, ho.OrdHour as Hour, ho.NumOrd as [Nr. Orders], DayO.PeriodDays as [Weekdays in period]
from HourO ho
inner join DayO
on ho.DayOfWeek = DayO.DayOfWeek
```